# Should we do something with [readonly] and similar tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

I stumbled across a single question tagged [readonlydictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readonlydictionary), and I looked long and hard at that tag trying to figure out if it made sense.

My initial action was to delete that tag and add [readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readonly) + [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary), even though [readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readonly) was [last edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10236772/revisions) in September of 2013 to include "DO NOT USE" in the excerpt and furthermore, in the wiki itself, instructing that it should be disambiguated.

Because there are so few variations of "readonly" (just ***seven***), and not much has changed in nearly two years, I have to disagree that "readonly" is ambiguous since it seems to be working fairly well on its own, covering 1,004 of the 1,098 questions with tags containing "readonly" in the tag name. I do believe it to be a fairly universal attribute that implies the same behavior across many technologies, and that disambiguating it would require the introduction of dozens of new tags and is probably not worth the effort at this point.

Here were my thoughts:

1. [readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readonly) × 1004 - **leave it be**
2. [readonlycollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readonlycollection) × 58 - leave alone, or retag to [readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readonly)+[collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collections) and burninate, or create a hyphenated synonym [readonly-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readonly-collection) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
3. [readonlyattribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readonlyattribute) × 21 - leave alone, or retag to [readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readonly)+[attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attribute) and burninate, or create a hyphenated synonym [readonly-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readonly-attribute) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
4. [isreadonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isreadonly) × 10 - **burninate** - usually refers to a property, field, or method name;  many could be re-tagged to [readonlyattribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readonlyattribute)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
5. [ireadonlydictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ireadonlydictionary) × 3 - **burninate** - C# interface name, retag to [readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readonly) + [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
6. [facebook-read-only-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-read-only-api) × 2 - I'm not sure this is actually a thing - **burninate**, retag to [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) + [readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readonly) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
7. [readonlydictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readonlydictionary) × 0 - will get **auto-deleted**, since I did retag the one question to [readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readonly) + [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

So, would I be wasting my time cleaning these up further? Do you have any additional suggestions?

Comment: Is there a good use case for readonly? Anything that it isn't "how to make this file readonly?"?

Comment: In general, it seems "readonly" tends to apply more to inputs and data collections than it does to actual files.

Comment: When I'm looking for help for the .NET class ReadOnlyAttribute, I'm going to use that entire term in the search field of my favorite search engine. My understanding was that tags were, in part, to help finding questions. Would removing `[readonlyattribute]` in favor of `[readonly]` and `[attribute]` or `[readonly-attributes]` enhance its searchability?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it doesn't make a difference, but it improves readability of the tag

Comment: @BhargavRao Seemed like a good question three years ago ;).

Comment: I was pretty surprised to see activity on this question from three years ago. Thanks for finishing what I started, @BhargavRao.

Comment: You're welcome, @Cᴏʀʏ. We've started on a crusade to clear the long backlog of burnination requests. The [tag:isreadonly] from your post is still left, feel free to join in. :)